# VBA Excel: Save to different directory

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use the following to save the file "Book1" with today's date. However, the file automatically saves in the same folder as "Book1". I am trying to save the files into a different directory, I am wondering how I can do that.

```
Sub filesave()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("Z:\Henry\test\Book1 " & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx")

End Sub
```

Comment: What directory do you want to save them in?

Comment: This "Z:\Henry\test\" is the rest of the folder path. You would change parts of this depending on where you want to save to. It is basically a nested structure with each "\" being a new level.

Comment: Let say I want the file in the Z:\Henry\test\Book1 directory to save in the directory Z:\David\test

Answer (score 2):

You use a folderPicker to allow the user to select their folder of choice. Be aware that the activeworkbook must be an xlsx.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim sFolder As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If sFolder <> vbNullString Then
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFolder & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
    End If
End Sub
```

Code adapted from [her](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/vba-select-folder-with-msoFileDialogFolderPicker/)e.

---

A similar version that drops the comparison with `vbNullString`, courtesy of @JohnyL:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim sFolder As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show Then
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFolder & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I use another, more concise, logic: `With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker): If .Show() Then sFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub: End With`. This way, you don't have to check `sFolder <> vbNullString`. :)

Comment: @johnyL Very nice. Mind if I appropriate that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
    Sub filesave()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Z:\Henry\test\Book1" _
    & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
    End Sub
```